# PHP uploading images

Tags: php

Im trying to upload an image after i sent a formular in uploads directory and create a subdirectory for every user.After i sent the formular the image i upload isnt move to the folder.

```
if (isset($_FILES['filename'])) {

   if (isset($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"]) && $_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"]) {
      $imagename = $_FILES["filename"]["name"];
      $check = mime_content_type($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"]);
      // $imgData = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']));
      // $imageProperties = getimageSize($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
      if ($check != 'image/png' && $check != 'image/jpg') {
         echo "<script>alert('Format fisier gresit');
         window.location.href='programare.php';
         </script>";
      }



      $target_dir = "uploads/" . trim($id, "\"");
      if (!file_exists($target_dir)) {
         mkdir($target_dir, 0777, true);
      }


      if (move_uploaded_file(basename($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"]), $target_dir)) {
         echo "The file has been uploaded.";
      } else {
         echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
         var_export($_FILES["filename"]);
      }
   } else {
      echo "<script>alert('Introduceti o poza cu problema');
      window.location.href='programare.php';
      </script>";
   }
}
```

This is the form code

```
<label>Imagine: </label><input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename" id="filename">
```

The subfolder is created but the image isnt uploading
[subfolder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNT0r.png)
[this is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMj5O.png)

UPDATE:

```
   $target_dir = "uploads/";
      $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["filename"]["name"]);
      if (!file_exists($target_dir)) {
         mkdir($target_dir, 0777, true);
      }


      if (move_uploaded_file(($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"]), $target_file)) {
         echo "The file has been uploaded.";
      } else {
         echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
         var_export($_FILES["filename"]);
      }
```

this works, it save all the images in the uploads folder, but the logic above, doesnt  move the files to new subfolder with the name of userid instead it replace the name of file , if the i upload image.png , it will upload 1image.png for user with id 1.

Comment: Have you verified permissions are correctly set on `$target_dir` so that the server is able to write to it?

Comment: yes it s not a problem

Comment: Probably something with `$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["filename"]["name"]);` not set to the correct place, how about try `print_r($target_file);`  before the `move_uploaded_file()` to see where its going?

Answer (score 1):

There is a few issues with your code.

For the `move_uploaded_file()` function, you need to pass the source and destination path relative to the current directory. However you have passed only the filename as first argument and you haven't specified the total destination file path for the second argument.

You have used `basename()` which returns the filename in the path.

Also your `$target_dir` variable doesn't contain the filename along with the directory.

Example for a correct path for 2nd argument: **uploads/1/filename.png**

Example of what you have passed as 2nd argument: **uploads/1/**

The warning:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory
```

The correct code would be (for the move_uploaded_file()):

```
<?php

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir . $_FILES["filename"]["name"])) {
         echo "The file has been uploaded.";
      } else {
         echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
         var_export($_FILES["filename"]);
      }

?>
```

Output:

```
The file has been uploaded.
```

[image]